# Textstream to read non-text files

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject

Is using the Microsoft scripting filesystemobject's OpenTextFile method (to set a textstream-typed or untyped variable), with open type = 8 (for appending), and seeing if that line of code can execute without error, a reasonably reliable way to ascertain whether or not the file is locked in any of the typical ways (i.e. another user or program has it open or locked in usage, or it actually has a file attribute of Read Only, but that last thing is not my primary goal, yes I already know about reading Attributes)...?

I've heard of doing this, but I'm just wanting to get some input. Obviously, the documentation on opentextfile generally focuses on the apparent assumption that you are actually working with TEXT files.

But my question then is two-fold:

1. Is the simple test of seeing if OpenTextFile (path,8) executes successfully pretty much a green light to assume it is not locked for some reason?
2. Will this work for other file types, like docx, PDF, etc. I mean I know the line of code seems to work, but is it equally applicable to the question of whether the file is locked for some reason.

Comment: VB.NET is not VBScript

Comment: Just for information, I have used this approach for [`.zip` files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28840196/2861476).

Comment: @plutonix: Actually, the scripting.filesystemobject object is available in both.  At least, I used it a few days ago in vbscript, and yesterday in vb.net, so unless I'm an alien or a magician, you may want to give that a second thought.  :)

at mcnd - Thank you.  It does seem pretty reliable, but I thought I'd get some input.  Thanks

Comment: That was in reference to the tag spam.  You either want an answer for VBA, VBScript or VB.NET because they are not the same.  There is no reason to use FSO in .NET

Comment: @Plutonix  I understand the point you are trying to make, I just don't agree with you.  I use FSO in .net all the time.  many people use IO and we could argue about this all day, but there doesn't seem to be a point.  In fact, very many people do use FSO in .net, especially in SSIS script tasks, where many people with light knowledge of either are coding where they're unfamiliar, so while it may not be the "ideal" method, nor as cool as the newer .net methods, you certainly can and many do use FSO in .net.

Comment: I've used FSO in all three, quite regularly.

Comment: So what this comes down to is filesystemobject doesn't "belong" to any one of the three - the fact that you believe it *shouldn't* be used in vb.net is very different than what you are saying, and basically demonstrates that you're just as incorrect in implying it simply must belong to vba or vbscript.  It can be used in all 3, and in fact, even javascript!